# iPhone not showing same results as simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator

I have an app that was developed for iOS 4 and 5 and I  migrated it to iOS7. When I test it on my iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1 is not showing the same results as the simulator.
Any suggestions?

Basically is not showing the initial segmented control, the map segmented control, the view associated with the control and it´s showing the scanner in a bigger size. The simulator showed the same issues before I restore the contents and settings in the simulator.

EDIT

If you watch very closely on the iphone it shows the segments and other elements of the view behind de navigation bar . But in the storyboard they appear right in the place that i want them. Is any form to consolidate my storyboard ??? Are any files that depend of the storyboard that i´m not including or generating.

The storyboard icon looks like black and also the .plist what does this means?

Comment: I think you might need to give us a bit more information than that

Comment: What exactly is not the same? Can you provide sample code where the result is different?

Comment: If restoring contents and settings of simulator fixed it, maybe you should delete and reinstall the app on your device.

Comment: The screenshots aren't showing in the question.

Comment: You have to look at the missing segmented controls

Comment: Probably you are using deprecated code, legacy code from iOS4 that don't work in the same way in iOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that i had installed the original app that is published in the app store. When I tested the current development on the iphone the existing app was replaced with the current one and that caused trouble. The solution was to delete the app from the device and then run again the current version of the app and that was all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simulator doesn't have the memory limitation as the device.
2. Simulator uses x86 arch, device uses ARM
3. It is a simulator, so it only "simulates" the behavior. Always test on device before submitting to the App Store.